# MediaSource gives cant' find variable in Safari

Tags: safari, webrtc, media-source

When I use JS:

```
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
```

That raises error in Safari12.

What's the syntax for Safari ?

Answer (score 1):

`new MediaSource()` works fine for me on Safari 12 on OSX. I suspect you're on iOS?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource#Browser_compatibility), iOS Safari 12 does not support `MediaSource`, only the desktop version does.

Comment: neither ios Safari 14